# How do I type a method to get a certain property from an object if it exists and the default property if it doesn't?

Tags: typescript

I have an object where every nested object in polygons has an id property, a default property and an unknown amount of properties of type `keyof typeof polygonsAnimate.polygons`.

```
const polygonsAnimate = {
    polygons: {
        q2: {
            id: 'q2',
            q2: "591.3,720.2 939.2,384.4 594,199.5 248.9,384.4 ",
            default: "591.3,720.2 939.2,384.4 594,199.5 248.9,384.4 ",
        },
        q0: {
            id: 'q0',
            q0: "594,199.5 228,1 110.5,1 110.5,255.1 248.9,384.4 ",
            default: "594,199.5 228,1 110.5,1 110.5,255.1 248.9,384.4 ",
        },
        //...
    },
    getStartSegment(id: keyof typeof this.polygons, prev: keyof typeof this.polygons) {
        const startSegment = prev in this.polygons[id] ? prev : `default`
        return this.polygons[id][startSegment] // <-- this throws an error
    },
}
```

With the method `getStartSegment` I want to get the respective property.

##### For example:

`getStartSegment('q2', 'q2')` should return `polygonsAnimate.polygons.q2.q2`,

`getStartSegment('q2', 'q0')` should return `polygonsAnimate.polygons.q2.default`

##### The error I get:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"q2" | "q0" | "q4" | "q1" | "q3" | "default"' can't be used to index type '{ id: string; q2: string; default: string; } | { id: string; q0: string; default: string; } | { id: string; q4: string; default: string; } | { id: string; q0: string; q1: string; default: string; } | { id: string; q3: string; default: string; }'.
  Property 'q2' does not exist on type '{ id: string; q2: string; default: string; } | { id: string; q0: string; default: string; } | { id: string; q4: string; default: string; } | { id: string; q0: string; q1: string; default: string; } | { id: string; q3: string; default: string; }'.ts(7053)
```

How can I type this correctly?